# Synchronize iPhone contacts with Windows 7 PC, without using iTunes

Tags: windows-7, windows, iphone, contacts, address-book

I want to copy my iPhone 3G contacts to my Windows 7 PC without going through iTunes.

When this is completed, I'll purchase an iPhone 4s that I would then like to synchronise with my PC contacts.

Please make the steps simple and concise as I am not very computer proficient!

Comment: Why  don't you want to use iTunes to do it?

Comment: use Gmail Exchange server, or any other compatible.. then import to your windows 7 app via gmail services.. simples. PS- Because he has the liberty of not using locked down iTunes.. i dont use itunes for anything, and i love it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get away from iTunes, you have an iPhone, it is an Apple Product, and they chain you to iTunes.

With that said, here is a simple guide you get by searching "importing iphone contacts to windows 7"

It is also for gmail syncing if you need that:
[image]

Once you find all the contacts in Windows Contact format inside the [Username]/Contacts folder, hit Export to save them all in CSV format.

[image]

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/import-iphone-contacts-to-gmail-via-windows-7/

**IF however you do want to find another way without itunes**
Try looking here:
http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/threads/how-to-back-up-my-contacts-without-using-itunes.56509/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you don't actually want to copy your contacts yo your PC, but rather to back them up (somewhere) so that once you get the new 4S you can upload them to the phone.

As Jakub said, the easiest way to do it is just by using iTunes.

If that is not an option, there are more convoluted ways to achieve your goal by making use of some kind online service, such as a Microsoft Exchange server. That will not backup your contacts to your PC, but rather to a server, which is a good thing because it will ease the transition to your new phone. Instructions for configuring google's exchange server syncing can be found here: http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740

Another option, unfortunately unavailable to you since it requires iOS5 (not available for the iPhone 3G), is to use iCloud as a contact syncing service.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible to use an iOS device without iTunes. You can buy apps, use iCloud to transfer documents, use other apps (DropBox) to do more, and backup to iCloud.
So yes.
However, iTunes is still a very useful tool. And it is free. So why not use it? If you had a toolbox with a hammer, wrench, screwdriver and saw, why would you intentionally decide to not use one of them in particular?
Maybe you are under the false impression that you have to buy into some sort of system if you use iTunes? That’s not so. It is just an app. You don’t need to use it for things you don’t want to use it for.
For instance, you could simply use iTunes as a way to back up your iPhone. Or, you could use it to easily transfer music from your computer to your iPhone. But you don’t need to buy music through iTunes or subscribe to podcasts. You can decide how you use it. And since it can be useful to you, then why not at least try it? It is just an app. Just a tool in your toolbox.

However:

Copy Trans Manager apparently allows you to manage your iPhone without using iTunes:

http://www.copytrans.net/copytransmanager.php

Alternatively Mobyko is a service that many of my friends use (available worldwide, just checked)

http://www.mobyko.com/Home.do

Uptact is a Contacts Sync App that will keep your Contacts Updated

http://www.uptact.com/

Answer (score 0):

**MAC OS / (equal method for Windows)**

```
HOW to transfert contact from older 3g to 5s for FREE

1) open "Carnet d'adresses" (contact)
2) delete all contacts

Itunes
3) open "Itunes", and connect older Iphone 3g
4) make save "sauvegarde"
5) in tab "Info" select "synchroniser les contacts", enable "tous les contacts", then press bouton "Synchroniser".
Now all contatcs are in "Carnet d'adresses"
6) eject older 3gs

Export to .vcf from 'Carnet d'adresses'
8) select all contact, right click "export vcard" myCards.vcf

Import myVCards.vcf to Icloud. 
8) Connect to "icloud" in web bowser.
9) select icon on the left down, import vcard then select file myCards.vcf
All contact are imported.

Import into Iphone 5s
10) In iphone "Réglage" > Icloud : enable contact
All contacts are synchronize with the Iphone.

YES YES YES

Itunes
11) Connect iphone 5s, then create new iphones in "Itunes"
make save "Sauvegarder"

Iphone 5s
12) Connect Apple Store, and install apps for backup contact. ex: Contacts Kit
13) make a backup and seed you a mail with all contacts (in .vcf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to sync contacts to Windows:
 
1.Turn off iCloud contacts on phone
 
2.Choose to keep data
 
3.On iTunes, in the info section of the phone, set it to sync with windows contacts
 
4.Clear your windows contacts (because it's a 2 way sync)
 
5.Sync phone
 

 
iTunes will sync all iCloud contacts with contact images to windows.
 
After sync finishes, turn on iCloud contacts on phone and merge contacts.